# Gnome-screenshot doesn't always work from keyboard shortcut

Tags: scripts, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I created a script to screenshot and save the screenshot directly, and I wanted to bind it to a keyboard shortcut. However, it only works about 50% of the time. If I run it from the terminal, it works every time.

It says

> Unable to select area using GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.

whenever I run it from the terminal.
In the shortcut, I've tried

```
script.sh
home/username/script.sh
bash "script.sh"
bash "home/username/script.sh"
```

The folder containing the script is in my $PATH

The script is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents/Screenshots/temp
DATE="$(date)"
gnome-screenshot -a -f "$DATE.png"
```

I have tried using #!/bin/sh instead

Update: I thought the script wasn't running every time i used the keyboard shortcut, but it turns out it was running, but gnome-screenshot was not always working. I've updated the title to reflect this
After searching it up online, I found that adding "sleep 0.1" before gnome-screenshot fixes this issue, but is there any other way of fixing this?

Comment: You can verify if the script is actually running by doing something like `date > ~/test.log` and checking if the contents of that file matches the current time

Comment: @KristopherIves I did that, and it turns out the script does run every time, it's just gnome-screenshot doesn't always work from the keyboard shortcut, but does always work from terminal

Comment: Here is the line of code throwing that error https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/blob/5f6d7db4faa8cde99fcccc16a9f15ac4bb3b188f/src/screenshot-area-selection.c#L321

Comment: Hi, please try `gnome-screenshot -a -f $HOME/Documents/Screenshots/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png`. No need to `cd` or to set `DATE`. Use `man date` if you don't like the timestamp format above. It maybe possible to bind the code directly to a keyboard shortcut instead of to a script which you then bind to a shortcut.

Comment: @DKBose thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, however, it still doesn't always work. In fact, even the default "Take a screenshot of an area" shortcut doesn't always work.